# Загрузить изображение с сервера с авторизацией

Tags: android, изображения

Мне нужно загрузить изображения с сервера и отобразить их в моем `ListView`.

Код который загружает изображение:

```
public class DownloadImage extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {

    Bitmap bmpimg;
      protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... urls) {
          InputStream in = null;
          try
          {
              URL url = new URL("http://hackersoft.ru/files/icons/hackersoft.png");
              URLConnection urlConn = url.openConnection();
              HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) urlConn;
              httpConn.connect();
              in = httpConn.getInputStream();
          }
          catch (MalformedURLException e)
          {
              Log.d(e.getMessage(), "1");
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          catch (IOException e)
          { 
              Log.d(e.getMessage(), "2");
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          bmpimg = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
          return bmpimg;

      }

}
```

Вот так я его юзаю:

new DownloadImage()
        {

```
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            bmp = result;
            super.onPostExecute(result);
        }

    }.execute("");
```

Возвращает bmp. Код работает отлично для прямых ссылок на изображения, но моя ссылка на изображение выглядит следующим образом:

```
http://login:password@host:port/путь_до_изображения
```

Т.е изначально происходит авторизация, а после нее уже загружаются изображения. Если использовать этот код, то изображения не загружаются. Как быть?

Comment: Что в логах? эксепшны срабатывают? Из браузера по тому же урлу доступ есть?

Comment: из браузера доступ есть, но для того, чтобы картинка отобразилась в браузере нужно нажать "ок". видимо из за этого изображение и не может подгрузиться, поэтому спрашиваю, как загрузить изображение с авторизацией. а в логах FileNotFoundException

Answer (score 1):

Все зависит от того какими способами сервер предоставляет аутентификацию

Возможно Вы можете обращаться к этой ссылке по защищенному соединению https и передовать логин пароль в хедерах.

Возможно если Вы предоставите ссылку на ресурс, то все решиться в одно мгновение)).

**а вообще что бы не писать 20 велобайков возможно стоит заглянуть** [сюда](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request)